# How to create a custom Inject Node in NodeRED?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I want to start my node with a button click, so that I do not have to put the inject node in front. How would that be possible to register a button click in the javascript file?

I have tried to put `node.on("input", async function(msg){/*some code*/})` inside the javascript file, where I register my node. I was  able to add this button [image] through this:

```
//HTML file script
<script type="text/javascript">
  RED.nodes.registerType('light', {
    category: "input",
    color: "#f3c12b",
    defaults: {
      name: {value: ""},
      plus: {value: ""},

      topic: {value: this.name},
      payload: {value: ""}
    },
    inputs: 0,
    outputs: 1,
    label: function(){
      return "Licht '"+this.name+"'" || "Licht";
    },
    button: {
      enabled: function(){
        return true;
      },
      onclick: function(){
         //I´ve put the code here, but then I have to reconfigure my functions
      }
    }
  });
</script>

//Javascript file --> register function
//Not getting any response
node.on("input", async function(msg) {
    msg = {};
    msg.topic = this.topic;
    msg.payload = "This is a new message!";

    node.send(msg);
});
```

I was expecting, that when I click this the node is sending a message, but the node is not responding anything.

Comment: Have you looked at what the inject node does in this situation?

Comment: Also, the Node-RED editor is not meant to be a dashboard, if you want to present a set of buttons to say turn lights on/off that's what the `node-red-dashboard` nodes are for

Answer (score 3):

The best bet here is to look at the inject node source code.
[inject.html](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/common/20-inject.html)
[inject.js](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/common/20-inject.js)

In the case of the inject node, the onclick function of the button parameter in the HTML file actually does a POST call to `/inject/{id}` on the server.

```
onclick: function() {
            
    ...

    var node = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "inject/"+this.id,
        type:"POST",
        success: function(resp) { ... }
    });

}
```

The inject JS file, which runs on the server, hosts an http endpoint at `/inject/:id` that when it's called gets the node by id and called `node.receive()` which acts as the trigger for it's input.

```
module.exports = function(RED) {

    ...

    RED.httpAdmin.post("/inject/:id", RED.auth.needsPermission("inject.write"), function(req,res) {
        var node = RED.nodes.getNode(req.params.id);

        ...

        node.receive();
        
        ...
    });
}
```